# Modify input names in childnodes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need help extending this JavaScript (borrowed from https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html):

```
var appCounter = 0;
function anotherApp() {
    appCounter = appCounter + 1;
var newAppField = document.getElementById("keyApp").cloneNode(true);
    newAppField.id = '';
    newAppField.style.display = 'block';
    var newApp = newAppField.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < newApp.length; i++) {
        var theName = newApp[i].name
        if (theName) {
    newApp[i].name = theName + appCounter;
        }
    }
    var insertApp = document.getElementById('keyApp');
    insertApp.parentNode.insertBefore(newAppField, insertApp);

    document.getElementById('appCount').value = appCounter
}
```

This works fine when element in my form is:

```
<div id="keyApp" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="application" id="application">
    <input type="text" name="usage" id="usage">
<\div>
```

But when I add `div`'s around the inputs (bootstrap styling reasons) I loose the ability to update the input names:

```
<div id="keyApp" style="display:none">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="application" id="application">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="usage" id="usage">
    </div>
<\div>
```

How do I extend the script to modify the input names in these new `div`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is now another layer, you need to get `newApp[i].childNodes[0]` now in order to get the actual input elements.

`newApp` now holds a list of the `div` elements with `col-md-2` styling, and you need to get the children inside of these `div` elements.

Comment: `newApp[i].childNodes[0]` points to `#text`, but `newApp[i].childNodes[1]` points to the input element... Appreciate the help though.